# How to detect Esc Key Press in React and how to handle it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I detect Esc keypress on reactjs? The similar thing to jquery

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        // <DO YOUR WORK HERE>
    }
});
```

Once detected I want to pass the info down components. I have 3 components out of which last active component needs to react to the escape key press.

I was thinking of a kind of registering when a component becomes active

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  onActive(escFunction){
    this.escFunction = escFunction;
  }
  onEscPress(){
   if(_.isFunction(this.escFunction)){
      this.escFunction()
   }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div class="root">
        <ActionPanel onActive={this.onActive.bind(this)}/>
        <DataPanel onActive={this.onActive.bind(this)}/>
        <ResultPanel onActive={this.onActive.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and on all the components

```
class ActionPanel extends React.Component {
  escFunction(){
   //Do whatever when esc is pressed
  }
  onActive(){
    this.props.onActive(this.escFunction.bind(this));
  }
  render(){
    return (   
      <input onKeyDown={this.onActive.bind(this)}/>
    )
  }
}
```

I believe this will work but I think it will be more like a callback. Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: Do you have no flux implementation to store which is the active component instead of doing it this way?

Comment: @BenHare : I still pretty new to it. I am looking into the feasibility of migrating into React. I have not tried flux, so you are suggesting I should look into flux for the solution. 

PS: How about detecting ESC keypress?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for keypress detection on the document level, like the first code block? Or is this for an input field? You can do either, I'm just not sure how to frame an answer. Here is a quick document-level for example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzaPW

Comment: Document level would be fine :)

Answer (score 345, accepted):

If you're looking for a document-level key event handling, then binding it during `componentDidMount` is the best way (as shown by [Brad Colthurst's codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzaPW)):

```
class ActionPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.escFunction = this.escFunction.bind(this);
  }
  escFunction(event){
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      //Do whatever when esc is pressed
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction, false);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction, false);
  }
  render(){
    return (   
      <input/>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that you should make sure to remove the key event listener on unmount to prevent potential errors and memory leaks.

EDIT: If you are using hooks, you can use this `useEffect` structure to produce a similar effect:

```
const ActionPanel = (props) => {
  const escFunction = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      //Do whatever when esc is pressed
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", escFunction, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", escFunction, false);
    };
  }, [escFunction]);

  return (   
    <input />
  )
};
```

EDIT for React 17:  React changed the way that document-level event binding is handled, which may cause this implementation to stop working if at some point in the chain `event.stopPropogation()` is called.  You can ensure that this function is called first by changing the last argument of the listener to `true` rather than `false`.  If you do this and also call `event.stopPropogation()`, other handlers that used to be called will no longer take place, so I would suggest avoiding that call if at all possible.

Comment: What is the third argument in `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`?

Comment: @jhuang https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - can be otions ou useCapture

Comment: @jhuang it's the useCapture argument which specifies whether or not to capture events [that usually don't bubble up like `focus`](https://gomakethings.com/wtf-is-use-capture-in-vanilla-js-event-listeners/).  It's not relevant for `keydown`, but it [used to not be optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) so it's usually specified for compatibility with IE<9.

Comment: I had to wrap `this.escFunction` into a function like `function() { this.escFunction(event) }`, otherwise it was executing at page load without any "keydown".

Comment: @Andras You probably put parentheses on `this.escFunction` in the `componentDidMount`.  You want to pass a reference to the function, not call it.

Comment: Another note too, if you decide to move the remove of the event listener somewhere else (like a cancel button) make sure you ALSO have it in componentWillUnmount() in case the user un-mounts the component some other way.

Comment: No need to include 'false' as the 3rd argument. It's false by default.

Comment: for the beauty I'd add [escFunction] as second parameter in the UseEffect (yeah the function is not changing)..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is `useCallback` here in this case? Wouldn't it just wrap it unnecessarily?

Comment: @cwj It has to be the same function that is added and removed to the event listener.  In this instance you're right because the `useEffect` only runs once, but I always just wrap generated functions in `useCallback` to get in a good habit.

Comment: The condition in `escFunction` should now be `event.key === "Escape"` as `keyCode` has been deprecated.

Comment: do we really need `useCallback` here folks? as the doc suggests, it is more likely to be used for performance optimization and only use when the insider function unnecessarily re-renders any large component

Answer (score 60):

Another way to accomplish this in a functional component, is to use `useEffect`, like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEsc = (event) => {
       if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        console.log('Close')
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);
    };
  }, []);

  return(<p>Press ESC to console log "Close"</p>);
}
```

Instead of console.log, you can use `useState` to trigger something.

Comment: What is the typescript type here for `event`?

Comment: I don't use typescript, so I don't know. But it's just a standard browser event callback. I guess typescript has some documentation you can check.

Comment: The type of the event is `KeyboardEvent`. Also, instead of using `event.keyCode`, one should use `event.key`, since `keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Answer (score 37):

You'll want to listen for escape's `keyCode` (27) from the [React `SyntheticKeyBoardEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) `onKeyDown`:

```
const EscapeListen = React.createClass({
  handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      console.log('You pressed the escape key!')
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <input type='text'
             onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
    )
  }
})
```

[Brad Colthurst's CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzaPW) posted in the question's comments is helpful for finding key codes for other keys.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that React appears to _not_ fire the `onKeyPress` event when the key being pressed is ESC and focus is inside `<input type="text" />`. In that scenario, you can use `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp`, both of which fire, and in the correct order.

Comment: `event.keyCode` is deprecated, you should use `event.key` which will return `Escape` when Esc is down.

Answer (score 26):

For a reusable React hook solution

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const useEscape = (onEscape) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleEsc = (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) 
                onEscape();
        };
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);
        };
    }, []);
}

export default useEscape
```

Usage:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
useEscape(() => setIsOpen(false))
```

Comment: The solution does not allow to change of onEscape function. You should useMemo and pass onEscape as the dep array for the useEffect

Comment: @Neo can you elaborate?

Comment: If you change the onEscape property to something else after loading it will still continue calling the original onEscape.  However this is a very unusual use case unless you are writing a library, so myself I wouldn't bother adding the complexity unless I needed it.

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle
const onEscape  useCallback(() => setIsOpen(false),[])
useEscape(onEscape)

and inside useEscape effect
const useEscape = (onEscape) => {
useEffect(() => {
  //mode code
}, [onEscpae]);
}

https://codeshare.io/21weNj

Answer (score 14):

React uses [SyntheticKeyboardEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) to wrap native browser event and this Synthetic event provides [named key attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values),
which you can use like this:

```
handleOnKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (['Enter', 'ArrowRight', 'Tab'].includes(e.key)) {
    // select item
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    // go to top item
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    // go to bottom item
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key === 'Escape') {
    // escape
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Comment: fun fact if you need to support IE9 and/or Firefox 36 or below, `e.key` for `Escape` comes back as `Esc` #triggered

Answer (score 4):

```
function handleEsc(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      close();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleEsc);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEsc);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit? While this may help the asker, in order to make the question helpful to others in the future please add some explanations as to what the code does.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make this work directly in your component instead of a hook, or if like me you are using this in a hook that DOES NOT return a <Component this worked for me.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      e.key === 'Escape' && setOpenState(false)
    })
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => e)
    }
  },[openState])
```

Answer (score -2):

React Hook

```
const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownFunction, false);
        return  () => { document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownFunction, false); };
    }, []);
const keydownFunction =(event)=>{
        if (event.key === "Escape") {  setAdd(false); }
        if (event.key === "+") { setAdd(true); }) }
}
```

Comment: There are already several answers to this question that take advantage of `useEffect` to answer the question with hooks. Please [edit] your answer to show how this one differs from those.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).