# Capturing 'escape' keypress in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events

I have a React app with the following structure:

```
<App>
  <Input/>
  <Lists>
    <List>
    .
    .
    <List/>
   </Lists>
</App>
```

Each list has modify button which makes the list display an input field if clicked and some text otherwise by toggling modify(a boolean state).

What I want to achieve is that on clicking the escape key user should be able to switch between both (the input field and the text).

What I've tried:

1. Use `document.addEventListener`, but I could not access the event handler (which is in the List class), I couldn't add it inside the class itself as it assumes `List.document` to be a property.
2. Use the `onKeyPress` synthetic event

I couldn't figure out how to add it to the app component (I want the user to click escape anytime, not focus on the input field or something and then press escape)

I added it to the Input field (the one replaced by the text in List) but it didn't work (It works with the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, I used `event.key==='Escape'`). I console logged the event and nothing comes up while it works fine for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

All suggestions appreciated :).

Comment: Also, you can see the effect I want by clicking on the search input field on this question page and pressing escape

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Esc Key Press in React and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440408/how-to-detect-esc-key-press-in-react-and-how-to-handle-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The escape key does not fire `keypress` event. You're going to want to listen for the `keydown` event.

```
class App extends PureComponent {
    // ...

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', callback);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', callback);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Also could you recommend any material that would be helpful for this kind of situation, I looked through the React docs and couldn't find this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'recommend any material that would be helpful for this kind of situation'. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like any docs, guides, papers or books that can be used for reference. Being a student i don't get to interact much with other developers so my list of useful and quality resources isn't very large.

Comment: Quite old answer but for anyone still looking for a reference about the difference bewteen `keypress` and `keydown`, apparently the `keypress` event is deprecated. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event.