# React + Hooks: Change State on ESC Press while in Fullscreen?

Tags: reactjs, fullscreen

I am trying to create a simple app that **goes into Fullscreen on Button Click and leaves Fullscreen on another**.

While I have that figured out, I am not able to update the state when I'm pressing **ESC** to leave the Fullscreen.

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Home() {
  const [isFullscreen, setFullscreen] = useState(false)

  const makeFullscreen = () => {
    setFullscreen(true)
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
  }

  const closeFullscreen = () => {
    setFullscreen(false)
    document.exitFullscreen()
  }

  console.log(isFullscreen)
  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-screen ${
        isFullscreen ? "bg-black" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div
        className={`w-5/6 space-y-6 text-center wrapper ${
          isFullscreen ? "hidden" : "visible"
        }`}
      >
        <button
          onClick={makeFullscreen}
          className={`btn btn-primary ${!isFullscreen ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}
        >
          START TEST
        </button>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={closeFullscreen}
        className={`btn btn-accent ${isFullscreen ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}
      >
        STOP TEST
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I played around with it using a few things I've found via Google, but they only work as long as it's not in Fullscreen.

Would be great to figure that out.

Bonus: A better way to enter/exit fullscreen :)

Comment: Have you played around with creating a keystroke listener on initial render? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440408/how-to-detect-esc-key-press-in-react-and-how-to-handle-it) may be of use. The only difference is for your functional component you'd write a `useEffect()` instance with an empty dependency array that declares the listener and returns a separate anonymous function removing that listener.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you would do that in that particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of research and I think I found a more elegant way of handling this, utilizing the [react-full-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-full-screen) npm package.

The way I implemented it:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react"
import { FullScreen, useFullScreenHandle } from "react-full-screen"

export default function Home() {
  const handle = useFullScreenHandle()
  const [isFullscreen, setFullscreen] = useState(false)

  const reportChange = useCallback((state) => {
    console.log(state)
    if (state === true) {
      setFullscreen(true)
    } else if (state === false) {
      setFullscreen(false)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-screen ${
        isFullscreen ? "bg-black" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div className={`w-5/6 space-y-6 text-center md:w-3/6 xl:w-2/6`}>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            handle.enter()
            setFullscreen(true)
          }}
          className={`btn btn-primary ${!isFullscreen ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}
        >
          
          START TEST
        </button>

       
      <FullScreen
        onChange={reportChange}
        className={`${
          isFullscreen
            ? "flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-screen"
            : ""
        }`}
        handle={handle}
      >
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            handle.exit()
            setFullscreen(false)
          }}
          className={`btn btn-info ${!isFullscreen ? "hidden" : "visible"}`}
        >
          STOP TEST
        </button>
      </FullScreen>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This automatically checks if the App is in fullscreen with the `reportChange` function and then sets the state of `isFullscreen` to true or false respectively.

Since it's `onChange`, it works automatically when leaving fullscreen with a press of ESC.

This solves the particular problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

I translated your code snippet into a code sandbox (for future SO posts, that helps a lot!) and added this missing `useEffect()` instance, seems to have accomplished your needs. It is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-hooks-change-state-on-esc-press-while-in-fullscreen-z8pyq?file=/src/App.js).

In short, the following needs declared:

```
  const escapeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      closeFullscreen();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", escapeHandler, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", escapeHandler, false);
    };
  }, []);
```

As noted in my comment above, that hook is adding the `keydown` listener to the document on initial render. That listener will stay on the document until this component unmounts and the clean-up phase of the hook is performed (executing the returned anonymous function).

Please see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) for more information on `useEffect()` clean-up and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) for more information on keys.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation! I found a solution in the meanwhile, see below! 

Good to know how it works the other way too tho.